# What is the generic name for a function of a real variable that starts flat, increases, then finishes flat?

Tags: real-analysis

What is the generic name for a function of a real variable that starts off flat, increases monotonically, and then finishes off flat?

The error function, the sigmoid function are a couple of examples, but I can't find a generic name.

Comment: Aren't the error function and [a sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) in strictly monotone, in general? In what sense do they "start and finish off flat"?

Comment: Bump function is maybe what you are looking for-used for smoothing.

Comment: Thank you.  By "start and finish off flat" I meant that the derivatives go to zero as the argument goes to +/- infinity.  "Sigmoid" is evidently the right term.  I learned that it is also used in geology.

Answer (score 0):

Those are called sigmoid functions.

Comment: Thank you. So 'sigmoid' is generic and not specific to the function x(t) = 1/(1+exp(t)) ?

Comment: x(t) = 1/(1+exp(-t))

Comment: @MartinA: That is the *logistic* function. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_curve

Comment: Thank you.  If I have correctly understood,  the error function, the logistic function (and for example the integral of a rectangular pulse) are all sigmoid functions.

Comment: @MartinA : ​ ​ ​ Hmm. ​ Sigmoid might imply some smoothness. ​ Otherwise, that's correct. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​